# Give an example of a convergent sequence that does not attain a maximum value

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I believe I solved this problem, can someone check it though?

I said $s_n=-(1/n)$

The $\lim{s_n}=0$, but $s_n<s_{n+1}$ for all n.

Is this correct?

Comment: yes, completely correct.

Comment: Yes true.  $0$ is the supremum but not maximum.

Answer (score 0):

A convergent sequence $(a_n)_{n=m}^{\infty}$ is bounded, that is, $|a_n| \le M$ for some positive number $M$. But it does not mean that there exists an $N \ge m$ such that $a_N=max\{a_n\}$. In fact, you can say that there is a finite supremum (the lowest upper bound) for the sequence, but you cannot say that the maximum exists.